# Rails scheduled SMS sender

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

I want send an SMS each 5 minutes to my users. At the moment, my application sends an SMS during the creation of an account.

```
# users_controller.rb
def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        @user.send_activation_email
        @user.send_daily_sms
        flash[:info] = "Veuillez contrôler votre boîte mail pour activer votre compte."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

# user.rb
def send_daily_sms

    # put your own credentials here 
    account_sid = '**********************' 
    auth_token = '**********************' 

    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API 
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token 

    @client.account.messages.create({
        :from => '**********', 
        :to => '***********', 
        :body => 'Salut',  
    })
  end
```

I already have scheduled mails working in my project by doing this :

```
# schedule.rb
every :day, :at => '12pm' do    
  rake "email_sender_daily"
end
# My task
task :email_sender_daily => :environment do |_, args|
  User.find_each do |user|
    UserMailer.daily_mail(user).deliver_now if user.daily == true
  end
end
# My UserMailer
def daily_mail(user)
@user = user
mail to: user.email, subject: "Mail journalier"
end
```

I'm showing you this because, with the UserMailer, I know how to access it from an other file. Here, I'd like to do the exactly the same for SMS, but how can I access the method that is in my Model ? If not, where can I put this method to be able to access it from my rake task ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me like you have all the parts you need. If `send_daily_sms` is a method in your `User` class then all you require is a rake task like so:

```
task :sms_sender_daily => :environment do |_, args|
  User.find_each do |user|
    user.send_daily_sms if user.daily == true
  end
end
```

And then your schedule.rb would look like:

```
every :day, :at => '12pm' do    
  rake "email_sender_daily"
  rake "sms_sender_daily"
end
```

I would warn that sending sms messages to all your users via one method that calls the API over and over again is somewhat fragile. If one message fails to send because of a timeout or some other error then the task will throw an error and not be able to complete sending all the messages.

I'd suggest sending both emails and sms messages by workers using a background queue, like Rails's ActiveJob. If you are on the latest Rails 4.2 then you can use a gem called [Textris](https://github.com/visualitypl/textris) that works much like ActionMailer and then you could define a `UserTexter` class like this:

```
class UserTexter < Textris::Base
  default :from => YOUR_NUMBER

  def daily_sms(user)
    @user = user
    text :to => @user.phone_number
  end
end
```

Then your tasks could look like this:

```
task :email_sender_daily => :environment do |_, args|
  User.find_each do |user|
    UserMailer.daily_mail(user).deliver_later if user.daily == true
  end
end

task :sms_sender_daily => :environment do |_, args|
  User.find_each do |user|
    UserTexter.daily_sms(user).deliver_later if user.daily == true
  end
end
```

Check out the [Textris](https://github.com/visualitypl/textris) documentation for more on how to use the gem.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: It's working thanks ! Now I'd like to replace the To number by the user number. I'm thinking about writing in my send_sms method self.phone = User.phone, then To => phone. Is this correct ? I also need to test in my task if user.daily == true AND user.phone is not null. I tried user.phone? but it wasn't working.

Comment: I made it work but I have an other problem now. I did phone = self.phone, and passing phone to the To =>. But having multiple users with different phones, it only sends one.

Comment: I tried with the Gem Textris, but it only sends to one number. Weird.

Comment: How are you setting the phone number? Are they saved on the user record in the database?

Comment: Yes, they are in the database as user.phone.

Comment: Could you maybe start a new Stack Overflow question with the code you are now using and we can answer that there rather than in the comments here?

Comment: Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613239/rails-send-multiple-sms