# Rails send multiple SMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have an app that is supposed to send an SMS to users every 5 minutes (value that will change later).

At the moment, my app is working, it sends SMS every 5 minutes, but to only one user. I don't know why the other users are ignored.

I'm using Twilio.

Here is my task :

```
task :sms_sender_daily => :environment do |_, args|
  User.find_each do |user|
    UserTexter.send_daily_sms(user).deliver_now if user.daily_sms == true && user.phone.present? (I tried with deliver_later too, same result)
  end
end
```

Here is my UserTexter :

```
class UserTexter < Textris::Base

  def send_daily_sms(user)

    @user = user

    # put your own credentials here 
    account_sid = 'AC25xxx' 
    auth_token = '059xxx' 

    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API 
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token 

    @client.account.messages.create({
        :from => '+14234350632', 
        :to => '+' + @user.phone, 
        :body => 'SMS journalier',  
    })
  end
end
```

I only have 3 users with 3 different number, but it only sends to one.

EDIT : 
When I put the send_daily_sms method in the user.rb model, and hardcode the "To" number, it sends the SMS 3 times to this number, since 3 users have daily_sms as true. Weird.

Comment: Does it send one time, or 3 times?

Comment: One time, to one number.

Comment: Are you using Textris in this example?

Comment: The send_daily_sms is in class UserTexter < Textris::Base. I edited the main message.

Comment: When using Textris, you should use the `text` method, like the `mail` method in Action Mailer, instead of calling to the Twilio API directly. However I don't think that is causing your issue here. What's the result if you open the Rails console and run: `User.find_each { |user| puts "#{user.phone}: #{user.daily_sms}" }`?

Comment: 417983*****: true
417873*****: true
417923*****: true

Comment: Are you using a Twilio trial account?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that being the issue, but as I said, when I put the method in user.rb, and hardcode for example my real phone number, it check every user that has daily_sms as true (here 3), and it sends me 3 SMS to my number.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe, from our discussion in the comments, that you are still using a Twilio trial account. When sending SMS messages from a trial account you can only send to numbers that you have verified. This includes your number, which you verify when you sign up. However it will probably not include the other numbers.

To resolve this, you can either verify the other numbers you are trying to test this with by going to this page in your account: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified

Otherwise you will want to upgrade your account, then you will be able to send messages to anyone.

You can check if Twilio was throwing errors when you were trying to send messages to unverified numbers by taking a look at the alerts section in the Monitor within your account. You can access that here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts

Hope this helps!

Comment: I verified an other real number, it still doesn't work. I added my real number phone to an other user, but it didn't send me 2 SMS either. The only way multiple SMS are sent, are when I put this method into user.rb. Do you understand or am I explaining it bad ? English is not my first language, sorry to bother you

Comment: Have you checked the Monitor to see if there were problems on the Twilio side?

Comment: When I run the task from the terminal, it sends me an SMS, but write that too : NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver_now' for #<Twilio::REST::Message:0x007fc7d10e5a88>
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/twilio-ruby-4.2.1/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/instance_resource.rb:68:in `method_missing'
/Users/Marco/Desktop/TBProject/lib/tasks/rake1.rake:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Ok, this is because you're not using Textris correctly and interacting with the Twilio API directly within a Textris class. Then, since it is throwing an error, it is not getting to the other two users. Check Kyle Decot's answer for how to use the `UserTexter` class (and make sure you've done the config too).

Comment: I tried to use Textris::Base with def send_daily_sms(user) text :to => user.phone end but I have this error Twilio::REST::RequestError: The 'To' number 41798352547 is not a valid phone number.

Comment: You probably need to add the "+" to the front of the number for the international format.

Comment: Earlier, I could send sms if you remember, and I had this : :to => '+' + @user.phone. Now I have this : text :to => "+#{@user.phone}" and I always have this error

Answer (score 0):

It's a little strange that you're interacting w/ the Twilio client directly here but also using Textris. Here is how I would do it (based on the textris readme).

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :wanting_daily_sms,
    -> { with_phone.where(daily_sms: true) }

  scope :with_phone,
    -> { where(arel_table[:phone].not_eq(nil)) }
end

# task

task :sms_sender_daily => :environment do |_, args|
  User.wanting_daily_sms.each { |u| UserTexter.send_daily_sms(u).deliver_now } 
end

# config/initializers/twilio.rb

Twilio.configure do |config|
  config.account_sid = 'AC25xxx'
  config.auth_token  = '059xxx'
end

# Gemfile

gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'textris'

# UserTexter

class UserTexter < Textris::Base
  default from: "Our Team <+14234350632>"

  def send_daily_sms(user)
    @user = user
    text to: @user.phone
  end
end

# app/views/user_texter/send_daily_sms.text.erb

SMS journalier
```

After adding the initializer above you'll need to be sure to restart your server.

Comment: I tried exactly like you said, it doesn't send SMS anymore

Comment: That doesn't give me a lot to go on. Does `User.wanting_daily_sms` yield any records? Does it give an error? What does the logs say?

Comment: How can I check that ? Sorry, I don't know much about Rails/Ruby

Comment: I got this when executing the task : rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `send_sms' for #<UserTexter:0x007ffab3186810>
/Users/Marco/Desktop/TBProject/app/texters/user_texter.rb:5:in `send_daily_sms'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/textris-0.4.0/lib/textris/base.rb:43:in `call_action'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/textris-0.4.0/lib/textris/base.rb:33:in `method_missing'

Comment: Your `UserTexter` class needs to inherit from `Textris::Delivery::Base` instead of `Textris::Base`

Comment: I now have : NoMethodError: undefined method `default' for UserTexter:Class. Weird because I have one.

Comment: I tried to use Textris::Base with def send_daily_sms(user)
     
      text :to => user.phone
    end but I have this error Twilio::REST::RequestError: The 'To' number 41798352547 is not a valid phone number.

Comment: I take it back. It does need to inherit from `Textris::Base`. Also take a look at my updated solution. I'm just looking at example from https://github.com/visualitypl/textris Also, maybe the phone number needs a leading `+`

Comment: Yes, that seems to right way to do it. The last issue now is that it's always writing me the error of the number not valid. I wrote this : text to: '+' + @user.phone but I still got the error.

Comment: I would take a look at https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally to see exactly how to format the number you're dealing with. I would probably also do `text to: "+#{@user.phone}"`

Comment: It's weird, earlier, I could send sms if you remember, and I had this in my user.rb : :to => '+' + @user.phone, it was sending sms. Now I have this : text :to => "+#{@user.phone}" and I always have this error, I tried with text :to => '+' + user.phone too